# Return Text from Ajax with function Aruments

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, return

```
      $add_text = get_branch_orientation($(jqTds[bup]).children().val());

      function get_branch_orientation(value){
        $.ajax({
          url : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>assign_orientation/get_branch_ori/'+value,
          dataType : 'text',
          success: function(data2){
             return data2;
          }
        });
      }
```

i am using this code for return some text..
1. but return 'undefined' when check alert function,
2. try to global variable but not working
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Ajax calls are asynchronous. You will not have that value assigned by doing a return. Can you try $add_text= data2 instead of return data2?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Why are you returning again? You just need to check if your value is getting updated to $add_text after your ajax call

Comment: @JohnDavid when does this AJEX should trigger ? `onChange`, `onKeyUp` etc ... ?? add your form too

Comment: please send to me your mail id.. i will send my total code

Comment: @JohnDavid This is not how SO works. All relevant code belongs in the question, so that it is visible for all users who might have the same problem or want to help. SO is not a personal help desk. A question must stand on it's own.

Comment: its working add.. async: false and  function get_branch_orientation(value){ var $result;
        $.ajax({
          url : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>assign_orientation/get_branch_ori/'+value,
          dataType : 'text',
          success: function(data2){
             $result=data2;
          }
        }); return $result
      }

Comment: @G_S thank you for your help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      //get branch orientation short code function
      function get_branch_orientation(value){
        var $result;
        $.ajax({
          url : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>assign_orientation/get_branch_ori/'+value,
          dataType : 'text',
          async: false,
          success: function(data2){
             $result= data2; 
          }
        });
        return $result;
      }
```

i forgeted the add async...